# Map canvas saveAsImage() method saves wrong image in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, geotiff-tiff, mapcanvas

I've been trying to write a small python script to output 2 tif's  based on given box extents. 
The script all works, box coordinates convert to project coordinates, zooms to right place (would like it to pause between zoom changes), just the 2 outputs are wrong, they both show the image that was displaying before the script is run.

```
import qgis.utils
import time

source_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(4326)#heographic
dest_crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(3857)
transform = QgsCoordinateTransform(source_crs, dest_crs)

myBox = QgsRectangle(0, 51,2,53)
new_box = transform.transformBoundingBox(myBox)

canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
canvas.setExtent(new_box)
#canvas.clearExtentHistory()
#canvas.clearCache();
canvas.refresh()
canvas.saveAsImage("c:/data/qgis_image.tif" ,None ,"TIF")

myBox = QgsRectangle(-4, 51,0,53)
new_box = transform.transformBoundingBox(myBox)

canvas = qgis.utils.iface.mapCanvas()
canvas.setExtent(new_box)
#canvas.clearExtentHistory()
#canvas.clearCache();
canvas.refresh()
canvas.saveAsImage("c:/data/qgis_image2.tif" ,None ,"TIF")
```